# Pull out the next number after word - R regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to extract the next set of numbers after the word "QUESTIONS". Example text:

```
x = c("GEOGRAPHY QUESTIONS TO 505 (708)", "MATHS QUESTIONS 606 (891)")
```

In both cases I would like to pull out the first set of numbers (the `505` and the `606`) and ignore the numbers in brackets.

Link to regex101: https://regex101.com/r/0W53uM/1

**Attempt to Solve**

I can pull out the number using a combination of the following, but it is not very elegant.

```
str_extract(x, "QUESTIONS TO (\d+)")]
```

or

```
str_extract(x, "QUESTIONS (\d+)")]
```

Comment: this doesn't solve it as it only works in the first case and not the second

Comment: Sure, use the same technique with an alternation, `"(?:(?<=QUESTIONS TO )|(?<=QUESTION ))\\d+"` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mqwnJZ/1). `"(?<=QUESTIONS TO |QUESTION )\\d+"` might work, too.